# Table view cell height based upon Dynamic height Table Height issues

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**Scenario -**

1. TableView height is set dynamically with respect to superview’s height using aspect ratio.
2. TableViewCell’s height is calculated based on table view’s height as :

   ```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return tableView.frame.height/2
    }
   ```

**Issue -**

Table view height is not calculated properly in the delegate method initially. But properly calculated after scrolling cells.

**Solutions tried:**

1. Reloading the `tableView` in `viewDidLayoutSubViews()`.
2. calling `cell.layoutSubViews()` in `cellForitemAtIndexPath`.

Any solution to achieve proper calculation for this tableView height?

Comment: is that return value directly `tableView.frame.height/2` ? i think it should be `tableView.frame.size.height/2`

Comment: What u actually want to calculate? tableview height or tableviewcell height? Are you using autolayout i.e. constraints based layout or frame based layout?

Comment: @Mukesh Both are valid.

Comment: Please tryout `tableView.layoutIfNeeded() ` before returning `return tableView.frame.size.height/2`

Comment: Try view.layoutIfNeeded() into viewDidLoad

Comment: Okay thanks for responding. Trying out suggestions..

Comment: Why are you using dynamic height but return a constant height? Arent you should return the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` if you want it to be dynamic?

Comment: @G.Abhisek I posted it as an answer

Comment: @Tj3n I want it to be dynamic based on tableView's height which varies as aspect ratio with super view height.

Comment: @G.Abhisek does my answer work for you?

Comment: @Mukesh Sorry, It didn't work ..

Comment: can you tell me in comment what issue facing with my solution ? screenshot have tableview & cell height is half height of tableview its working properly in my demo

Comment: Did you try setting your table view's height constraint as aspect ratio with your superView.

Comment: yes i had given aspect ratio too with superview

Comment: @Mukesh Can you please send me the sample code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136862/discussion-between-mukesh-and-g-abhisek).

Answer (score 2):

Please tryout `tableView.layoutIfNeeded()` before returning `return tableView.frame.size.height/2`

Comment: Try call this earlier, and also try call `cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()` before return cell

Comment: Move `tableView.layoutIfNeeded()` out of the tableview delegate and add it before any `tableview reload`  method.

Answer (score 0):

Friend declare CGRect in vc.h file

```
CGRect tblFrame;
```

then set your tableView frame to that tbleFrame in vc.m `viewDidLoad:` method,

```
tblFrame = self.tableView.frame;
```

Then,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
             return tblFrame.size.height/2
    }
```

[image: Dynamic cell height based on tableView]